# (Ir)reducible polynomials over some field

Tags: polynomials

When I want to factor a polynomial, say $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$,
I can do

`Factor[p(x), Extension -> {Sqrt[2]}]`

what if I want to factor a polynomial with more than one variables $p(x,y,z)$ over a *specific* field, say $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y,z]$?
where $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field with 2 elements.

Comment: It might be helpful to include what happens when you try `Factor[p[x,y,z], Modulus -> 2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```
FactorSquareFree[x^6 + (y + z)^4, Modulus -> 2]
```

> (x^3 + y^2 + z^2)^2

```
FactorSquareFree[x^6 + (y + z)^4, Extension -> Sqrt[-3]]
```

> x^6 + y^4 + 4 y^3 z + 6 y^2 z^2 + 4 y z^3 + z^4